# How do I change the colour of all lines to red begining with a % symbol?

Tags: linux, shell-script, colors

When I use

`sed -i "s,.*%.*,$(tput setaf 1)&$(tput sgr0),g"  A.log`

the whole line vanishes and when I use

`sed -i "s,^%.*,$(tput setaf 1)&$(tput sgr0),g"  A.log`

only the first character(`%`) turns red.

What should I do?

EDIT : Actually the whole line doesn't vanish, I was using `more` but when I used `less -R`
I saw this (with a control M character) and % in red color.

```
 % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.^M
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
sed -i "s/^%.*$/$(tput setaf 1)\\0$(tput sgr0)/" A.log
```

And use `cat -v file` for displaying content without parsing colors.